# Is there any command in Azure CLI similar to cat in bash script? GCP's gsutil has support for cat command

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-cli

I'm a beginner to shell scripting with Linux and cloud shells. I was actually using GCP's gsutil command with cat to perform a operations like reading certain content of a bucket file, which is working great.

I wanted to do the same for Azure blobs but Azure CLI doesn't support any similar command.

Sample code:

```
gsutil cat $PATHOFBUCKETFILE
```

I want something like:

```
az storage blob .... cat $BLOBNAME
```

P.S. I **dont** want to first download the blob locally and then read the content.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, any command which implements this has to download the contents somehow. It's nice of course if it does this transparently and doesn't leave temporary files behind (though caching might be a good idea if the files are big).

Comment: Yup yup exactly. I just want it to be transparent and not to save it locally and then remove it. Secondly, the files are text files and not too big.

Comment: @HamzaAzam I don't think that's doable as of today. Feel free to suggest it here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```sh
az storage fs file download \
  --account-name "${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}" \
  --file-system "${CONTAINER_NAME}" \
  --path "${BLOB_NAME}" \
  --destination /dev/stdout
```

For more information, see [`az storage fs file` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_fs_file_download).

Another option, which works with Azure blob URLs, is to use `azcopy copy` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)) as follow:

```sh
azcopy copy \
  --from-to BlobPipe \
  https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${CONTAINER_NAME}/${BLOB_NAME}
```

However for this you need at least the "Storage Blob Data Reader" role. The contributor role is sufficient to read the file with `az` CLI, but not with `azcopy`. Without at least this permission you will get an error "403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.". For more information see these github issues [Azure/azure-storage-azcopy#790](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/790) and [Azure/azure-storage-azcopy#499](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/499)